# How to set default value for HTML select in Bootsrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Using `jquery`, I was able to set a default value to `HTML` select easily.

```
$(function() {
    var temp="a"; 
    $("#MySelect").val(temp);
});

<select name="MySelect" id="MySelect">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

But this is not working in the `bootstrap modal` select tag.
I also tried it by reinitializing the modal.

```
  $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#MySelect').val(temp); 
        });
```

But this is also not working. What is the issue in here?

Comment: Can you use the HTML default selected? `<option selected="selected" value="a">a</option>` Or does this have to be done programmatically?

Comment: I need to do this dynamically

Comment: Is `temp` set above your code? What do you see in the console?

Comment: @Shashika : Check my answer i have created a working fiddle for you. I believe you are not giving the correct class of modal use id instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AjayMathur/Lztq2sba/2/):

Js:

```
$('#confirm').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    var temp = "b";
    $('#MySelect').val(temp);
})
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for when selected="selected" isn't respected in a Bootstrap Modal also, because of how the Modal overrides focusing elements within it.

Answer (score 0):

You can select option using `selected` property:

`<option selected="selected">`

or you may use jquery:

```
var country = document.getElementById("MySelect");
MySelect.options[MySelect.options.selectedIndex].selected = true;
```